# How to switch animation from Angular to css

Tags: css, angular, animation, css-animations

I have a fade-in/out animation working perfectly using `@angular/animation`, but I need to pass this animation to css and take this dependence off of `@angular/animation`

My animation (I just pass the `[@fadeInOut]` attribute in my `div` and it works):

```
animations: [
    trigger('fadeInOut', [
      state(
        'void',
        style({
          opacity: 0
        })
      ),
      transition('void <=> *', animate(300))
    ])
  ]
```

i tried to do this in css but it didn't work:

```
.fadeinout{
  animation: fade 0.3s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes icon-fade-in-out {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }

}
```

Comment: Please could you put up a complete working snippet that we can try as I have been unable to see the fadein/out effect not working - seems fine to me but it may be you are after a different effect from what I saw. And did you want the animation to run either forever or for several cycles?

Comment: Hi. I want it to fade-in when the element enters the screen and fade-out when the element leaves (when I click to close or when it stays on for a while that I set). I fixed the css of the question. The angular animation works perfectly, but the css just the fade-in

Comment: You probably also need Javascript and, for exmaple, IntersectionObserver.

Answer (score 1):

you should be using keyframes and webkit-keyframes incase the browser doesn't support it.  I like to create 20 steps on mine because I think it looks a lot cleaner and not so jumpy on the fade in.

```
.fade-in {
    -webkit-animation: fade-in .8s steps(20, end) both;
            animation: fade-in .8s steps(20, end) both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade-in {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
@keyframes fade-in {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
```

you can read about it here:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/

in your function you can use renderer2 - in response to your comment this is how we did it and it works.  I could have combined the classes but we were testing each on individually to make sure they injected into the Dom timely and in order.

```
 const loading= document.getElementById('loading');
      const signinElement = document.getElementById('signinelement');

    this.renderer.removeClass(signinElement, 'show');
    this.renderer.removeClass(signinElement, 'fade-in');
    this.renderer.removeClass(loading, 'hidden');

    this.renderer.addClass(signinElement, 'hidden');
    this.renderer.addClass(signinElement, 'fade-out');
    this.renderer.addClass(loading, 'show');

    this.renderer.addClass(loading, 'fade-in');
    setTimeout(()=>{
      


  // this.renderer.addClass(signinElement, 'show');
  // this.renderer.addClass(signinElement, 'fade-in');
 
      setTimeout(()=>{
        this.signin.googleSignin();
      }, 500)
     

    }, 500)
```

Comment: Hi Cris, tks for the answer. This works for fade-in, but it doesn't work for fade-out. when I click to close the element or when the element stays the time on the screen that I determined, it closes without animating. It has the same behavior as the css I put

Comment: we went through this too man.  I ended up using renderer 2 and appending the class via a function and then clearing it.

Comment: added the renderer 2 typescript so you can see we did it hope it helps you.  I also am not a fan at all of angular animations.

Comment: we also force a full second to view the animation through a timeout - and you see our animation is only .8seconds